Two men talk in a small room about god and other deep meaning subjects?
One of the two men wants to kill himself and he is saved by the other one. All the other scenes take place in a small apartment room where they talk about different things like family or god.
Other details I remember

The man who can be interpreted as the savior is afro american.
the dialog of these two characters is creating the entire movie.
I don't think that there are any other characters besides these two.

